# docker how to add host entry to generic image available in docker repository

Tags: docker

A generic selenium/node-firefox docker image available in docker repository. I need to make changes/append to the image so that it have our test environment host entries.

What would be the best approach to do this. Should I just take the source and make the changes and build my own image?

In terms of maintainability it is possible to do it such a way that it always gets the base image and my changes append to it to make a new image? If so how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a docker container, there is an `add-host` argument that lets you specify what host entries you need to make available to the container. This would be similar to if you updated the /etc/hosts file.

```
docker run --add-host myserver:192.168.0.100 the-image-name
```

You don't need to update the source image to accomplish this. If you need to perform customizations to a docker image beyond what the runtime arguments give you, you can always derive your own Dockerfile from the image (although you should research best practices around deriving image files and not making deeply nested image files).

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) is a reference page.

Comment: is there anything similar that can be done when running it through docker-compose?

Comment: @kumar Yes, docker-compose has the same setting. See the `--host` setting https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/.